# Location Services from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Can i turn the Location Services on from within my application. In other words can i control the on or off state of Location Services from my iphone application. Solutions are appreciated in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question: no, you cannot change device settings from your code.

Comment: so you say i have to do individual setting for that app at Settings > Location Services

Answer (score 2):

CLLocationManager [`startUpdatingLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) & [`stopUpdatingLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopUpdatingLocation) is what you want, assuming you're talking about getting Location Services updates into your application.

As for the whole device itself, @TomvanderWoerdt is correct (& +1 for him!)  :-)